# Could not debug program when upload more than 2GB file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a fileuploder where i am uploading file and save it in DB. Its working fine till 2 GB but after 2 GB if i want to upload then neither it is working nor the code is debugging.

I have set in web.config file for 4 GB access :-

maxRequestLength="4194304"

and

maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"

I am using ------

Framework :- 4.5
IIS :- 7.5
Managed Pipeline mode :- Integrated

I have changed Managed Pipeline mode into Classic also.

Can we upload more than 2 GB file.

Comment: does your db allows such a large file? What datatype you have used? You can check its limits

Comment: Its Image datatype and I am not insert data in single row , I have split it into multiple row and insert data into DB.

Comment: Image datatype in SQL Server have 2GB maximum size https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: How are you splitting the file? Can we see a code sample? Also i would recommend trying Varbinary[MAX] as datatype and then see

Answer (score 0):

The below article describes about the  maximum file size allowed.
There is a limit specified becoz of health monitoring in asp.net where the worker process uses little more than 1 gb.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323246